# Failed to fetch manifest with key Deploying to beanstalk with new application version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm just started having issues today with deploying a new version of my application to amazon eclastic beanstalk. I've been able to previously successfully applications to this server with no problems, but today i started encountering this error inside of `/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log`

```
[2019-03-28T19:41:08.048Z] WARN  [2639]  : Failed to fetch manifest with key resources/environments/e-ckucpxbbk5/_runtime/versions/manifest_1553802024849 from elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-981331869848, reason: Access Denied. Retrying after 1.5171911696026408 seconds.
[2019-03-28T19:41:09.565Z] INFO  [2639]  : Loading manifest from bucket 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-981331869848' using computed S3 key 'resources/environments/e-ckucpxbbk5/_runtime/versions/manifest_1553802024849'.
[2019-03-28T19:41:09.572Z] WARN  [2639]  : Failed to fetch manifest with key resources/environments/e-ckucpxbbk5/_runtime/versions/manifest_1553802024849 from elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-981331869848, reason: Access Denied. Retrying after 6.869582456562737 seconds.
[2019-03-28T19:41:16.442Z] INFO  [2639]  : Loading manifest from bucket 'elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-981331869848' using computed S3 key 'resources/environments/e-ckucpxbbk5/_runtime/versions/manifest_1553802024849'.
[2019-03-28T19:41:16.559Z] WARN  [2639]  : Failed to fetch manifest with key resources/environments/e-ckucpxbbk5/_runtime/versions/manifest_1553802024849 from elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-981331869848, reason: Access Denied.
[2019-03-28T19:41:16.560Z] ERROR [2639]  : Failed to fetch manifest with key resources/environments/e-ckucpxbbk5/_runtime/versions/manifest_1553802024849 from elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-981331869848, reason: Access Denied. (ElasticBeanstalk::ManifestDownloadError)
        at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/manifest.rb:147:in `rescue in fetch'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/manifest.rb:100:in `fetch'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/manifest.rb:57:in `update_cache'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:58:in `load'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:134:in `load_command'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:66:in `execute!'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/bin/command-processor:45:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `load'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `<main>'
caused by: Access Denied (Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied)
        at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_sse_cpk.rb:18:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_accelerate.rb:33:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:20:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:21:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.0/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.3.0/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:207:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.3.0/lib/aws-sdk-resources/request.rb:24:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.3.0/lib/aws-sdk-resources/operations.rb:41:in `call'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-resources-2.3.0/lib/aws-sdk-resources/operation_methods.rb:19:in `block in add_operation'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/manifest.rb:126:in `fetch'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/manifest.rb:57:in `update_cache'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command.rb:58:in `load'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:134:in `load_command'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/lib/elasticbeanstalk/command-processor.rb:66:in `execute!'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/beanstalk-core-2.12/bin/command-processor:45:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `load'
        from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/command-processor:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm not really sure what has changed, I have not adjusted any security groups related to this application and I can successfully upload the zip file via the beanstalk web GUI. It just seems to fail to deploy with that error log.